# Unix filesystem look up

Tags: unix, filesystems

How to get the list of all the files and folders in the root dir including sub-folders and their files.

Comment: Do you mean from a program, or using the shell, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (with Ewan's modification):

```
ls -R /
```

Comment: This will work if you have changed into the root dir.  Otherwise use `ls -R /`.

Comment: list would be quickly populated with ls -R . You can opt for paging with [ls -R | more]  if you are you specifically looking for something..type q to quit

Answer (score 6):

or this: find /

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it programmatically I'd recommend [readdir()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/readdir.html) and [opendir()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/opendir.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
man find
```

In all seriousness though,

```
find / -maxdepth 2
```

That should show you the root directory, folders in /, and the contents of those folders. If you want the subdirectories of the subdirectories, use -maxdepth 3, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

use find command eg

```
$ find /path -print
```

or if you have tree installed

```
$ tree /path
```